Problem with authorization to Google Vision API bad credentials
I created a Google Vision Machine Learning Model, and a credentials file, and if I make a request with these credentials it works, but if I do a request to model, it doesn't works.
# URL for making prediction requests
url = "https://us-central1-aiplatform.googleapis.com/v1/projects/reflected-flame-422918-n5/locations/us-central1/endpoints/3216186959965716480:predict"

....

    # Load service account credentials from JSON file
    with open("/home/reflected-flame-422918-n5-5c005a40ee20.json", "r") as json_file:
        credentials_info = json.load(json_file)

    # Create credentials object from service account info
    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(credentials_info)

    # Obtain OAuth 2 access token
    access_token = credentials.token

    # Set authorization header with the access token
    headers = {
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }

    # Encode image data to base64
    image_base64 = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode("utf-8")

    # Prepare request data
    data = {
        "instances": [
            {"content": image_base64}
        ]
    }

    # Send POST request for prediction
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)

And get this error:
Prediction request failed with status code: 401
Response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo",
        "reason": "ACCESS_TOKEN_TYPE_UNSUPPORTED",
        "metadata": {
          "service": "aiplatform.googleapis.com",
          "method": "google.cloud.aiplatform.v1.PredictionService.Predict"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

No cars of the desired brands found in the image.

Process finished with exit code 0


I tried to connect the Google Vision API like this, but it doesn't works too:
# credentials
credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("/home/reflected-flame-422918-n5-5c005a40ee20.json")

# trying to connect to my model
client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient(credentials=credentials)
model_id = "3216186959965716480"  # Id of my model


